# How can I disable Rails 4.2 web-console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm not using the console and it's using up space (especially when I have my chrome console open). Is there a config option to disable it?

Answer (score 3):

I think you should remove this line from `Gemfile`

```
gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
```

Comment: This is not a real answer, if he has to remove it from the Gemfile, explain what he should remove clearly rather than answering a question with another question.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, it was not `web-console` but [`better-erros` gem](https://github.com/charliesome/better_errors/wiki/Allowing-access-to-the-console)

And I successfully disabled it with

```
BetterErrors::Middleware::ALLOWED_IPS.clear
```

in `config/initializers/local.rb`.

So you should try clearing `web-console`'s IP's in the similar way:

```
config.web_console.whitelisted_ips = []
```